# Can someone please explain the difference between ASP.NET MVC & .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hello I have built an application using asp.net MVC, this project is all working well but I am finding a lot of documentation with Stripe has documentation depreciated, however, the documentation is fine for asp.net core

Is it a massive change between the two types, why doesn't it seem to work with my one. I am new to all of this but it doesn't really make a lot of sense to me so please explain in lamens terms and link some articles if it would help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your confusion :D I've worked with ASP.NET for very long (since web forms). I'll try to explain to the best of my understanding.

MVC is a design pattern that has seen a lot of success and has been adapted widely by several frameworks. ASP.NET MVC is the dot net implementation of the MCV pattern.

ASP.NET Core is a redesign of ASP.NET with a lot of new features and benefits. The biggest advertised differences is the fact that DOT NET CORE is open source and cross platform.

In an asp.net core web application you will still see the MVC pattern with several improvements since ASP.NET MVC.

If your project works perfectly you don't have to do a complete redesign. The frameworks will keep updating and as developers we need to stay updated but we can't go and redesign every project. New projects are a different story. If you start something new definitely consider using ASP.NET Core.

Here is one of Microsoft's docs that helps understand the difference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

If you split your application into different projects for the front-end stuff, business logic, and data access, it shouldn't be too painful to port it over. The business and data access code should mostly work the same way. it's just the bit of MVC presentation stuff that will be markedly different.

Comment: Thanks for this :) I found you were right the main difference I found was with ASP.NET Identity for the account registration